# Show that coefficents of $\prod_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(x+(2k-1)^2)$ (apart from coefficent of $x^{0}$ & $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$) are multiples of prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Given that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+(2k-1)^2)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} c_{i}(n)x^{n-i}$$
how can we show that :
$$\forall i \in \left[1,\frac{p-3}{2} \right] \space c_i\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)\equiv 0 \space \text{mod} \space p$$ where $p$ is a prime number.
What theorems from number theory can help me prove this identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what theorems from number theory can help me prove this identity?

You have a polynomial (in this case, $-c_0+\prod{(x+(2k-1)^2)}$) that you want to show is the zero polynomial mod $p$.

**Theorem.** The integers mod $p$ are a field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Thus we can reinterpret your question as: "I have a polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.  How do I show $f(x)$ is the zero polynomial?"

**Theorem.** If a polynomial $f(x)$ has degree at most $k$ and vanishes at $k+1$ points, then $f(x)=0$.

This is the so-called ["Combinatorial Nullstellensatz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Combinatorial_Nullstellensatz); it is commonly used to show uniqueness of polynomials.  For example, recall

**Theorem. (Fermat)** For all $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$, $a^{p-1}=1$.

[**Theorem. (Wilson)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) $$\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}{j}=-1\qquad\text{in }\mathbb{F}_p$$

To prove these results, consider the action of the involution $a\mapsto a^{-1}$.  Combining them, we find that the unique polynomial of degree less than $p-1$ vanishing at all elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ that is $-1$ at $0$ is $x^{p-1}-1$.

One might hope to show that your function vanishes a lot; I will take a slightly different tack.

**Theorem.** Fix $a\neq1$.  $0$ is the unique element $z\in\mathbb{F}_p$ (see above) such that $az=z$.

Thus it suffices to show that your coefficients satisfy such a formula.  How could this arise?

Well, substituting $x\mapsto ax$ sends $c_ix^k\mapsto(c_ia^k)x^k$.  So we want to examine your polynomial under substitutions of this form.

Our last key step is to recall the theory of *quadratic residues*: a number is a quadratic residue when it is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

**Theorem.** The [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), which is $1$ on quadratic residues and $-1$ elsewhere, is a multiplicative homomorphism.

This lets us divide $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ into four categories.  First, let $Q$ be the quadratic residues of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ and pick any $r\in\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}\setminus Q$.  Then $$\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}=Q\sqcup rQ$$

Second, let $O$ be the odd elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ (considered as the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$).  Then $$\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}=O\sqcup 2O$$

Thus $|Q|=|O|=\frac{p-1}{2}$.  But $\{o^2:o\in O\}\subseteq Q$, and (since $p$ is an odd prime), $o\mapsto o^2$ is injective on $O$.  So we must have $Q=\{o^2:o\in O\}$.

Now your function is $$f(x)=\prod_{o\in O}{(x+o^2)}=\prod_{q\in Q}{(x+q)}$$  We also know that \begin{align*}
x^{p-1}-1&=\prod_{a\in\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}}{(x+a)} \\
&=\prod_{q\in Q}{(x+q)(x+rq)} \\
&=\prod_{q\in Q}{(x+q)\cdot r(r^{-1}x+q)} \\
&=r^{\frac{p-1}{2}}f(x)f(r^{-1}x) \\
&=-f(x)f(r^{-1}x)
\end{align*} where the last computation is from the fact that $r$ is a nonresidue.

Substituting $x\mapsto r^{-1}x$, we must also have $$x^{p-1}-1=-f(r^{-1}x)f(r^{-2}x)$$ and so $f(x)=f(r^{-2}x)$.

But $r$ was any quadratic nonresidue!  So we're done.

I leave two questions to you: why does this argument *not* also force the constant term and leading term to vanish?

Comment: thank you for providing these 2 theorems. But I don't understand how can option 2 be used, how can we chose the correct a, can you provide a proof sketch using theorem in option 2 ?

Comment: @mathlover123: You're right; it doesn't work.  Sorry!

Comment: it is okay no problem! But can you provide a proof using option 1 because I'm not the best with fields and abstract algebra.

Comment: @mathlover123: I've changed it to a full answer.